# Partial parsing and recovery of Menhir

Tags: parsing, ocaml, menhir, merlin

There is a very small [calculator in Sedlex and Menhir](https://github.com/chengtie/sedlex-menhir). Now, I would like to make the calculator to be able to parse expressions like `1+`. So I modified `parser.mly` to

```
... ...
main:
    expr EOL                { $1 }
;
expr [@recovery (E_int 0)]:
    INT                     { E_int $1 }
  | BOOL                    { E_bool $1 }
... ...
```

But evaluating `1+` still returned an error `Fatal error: exception Parser.MenhirBasics.Error`.

Could anyone help?

Comment: [Also asked on discuss](https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/try-partial-parsing-and-recovery-of-menhir/9310). Please also cross-link when you cross-post, to prevent people from spending a lot of time trying to help you solve a problem that's already been solved elsewhere.

Comment: It looks like the line you added is missing here, no? The code you put is the one already existing in sedlex-menhir

Comment: @Lhooq The repository contains already the line with `[@recovery (E_int 0)]`, which raises an error for `1+`.

Comment: And where does this `[@recovery (E_int 0)]` come from? Couldn't find it in menhir's manual

Comment: For instance, Merlin uses `recovery`, see [here](https://github.com/ocaml/merlin/blob/master/src/ocaml/preprocess/parser_raw.mly) and [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.06702.pdf).

Comment: It looks like they defined their own preprocessing for this. recovery is not a keyword in Menhir. Try using the old fashion way with the last token being error and returning `E_int 0` (you'll need to enable the legacy strategy and for this you need to enable --table I think)

Comment: And it would be a good thing to create a proper dune file to build with dune and put your flags for menhir in it

Comment: Thank you... I did a quick search... do you have any example of "the last token being error and returning..."?

Comment: http://gallium.inria.fr/~fpottier/menhir/manual.html#sec65
Just write `| error { E_int 0 }` as the last rule for `expr`

Comment: `| error { E_int 0 }` does work with my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Augmented summary of my comments:

- `[@recovery ...]` is a construct specific to Merlin
- As of now (13/02/2022) it is still possible to define your own error recovery by using the special `error` token like this:

```ml
main:
    expr EOL                { $1 }
;
expr [@recovery (E_int 0)]:
    INT                     { E_int $1 }
  | BOOL                    { E_bool $1 }
  | error                   { E_int 0 }
```

From [menhir's manual](http://gallium.inria.fr/%7Efpottier/menhir/manual.html#sec65):

- > If the error token is used to survive an error and continue parsing, then the legacy strategy should be selected.
- > `--strategy strategy`.   This switch selects an error-handling strategy, to be used by the code back-end, the table back-end, and the reference interpreter. The available strategies are `legacy` and `simplified`.

From [OCaml weekly news](https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/ann-new-release-of-menhir-20211230/9077/1):

- > Grammars that make more complex use of the error token, and therefore
  > need the legacy strategy, cannot be compiled by the new code back-end.
  > As a workaround, it is possible to switch to the table back-end (using
  > --table --strategy legacy) or to the ancient code back-end (using
  > --code-ancient). In the long run, we recommend abandoning the use of
  > the error token. Support for the error token may be removed
  > entirely at some point in the future.

This way of doing will most likely not work in a near future but it does for now and it appeared to be the simplest way of doing what OP asked.